# Broadcast Receiver Constantly Restarting

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm making a widget which I want to update every second (It's like a countdown/timer widget), so I'm using a AlarmManager and a broadcast reciever to achieve this without waking the phone and using up all the battery, but I keep getting a constant stream of errors in LogCat when running the widget:

```
08-18 18:40:43.368     390-1988/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.dysign.livetubecountdown (pid 9784) has died.
08-18 18:40:44.282      390-414/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.dysign.livetubecountdown for broadcast com.dysign.livetubecountdown/.WidgetAlarmManager: pid=9809 uid=10144 gids={50144, 3003, 1028}
08-18 18:40:44.306    9809-9809/com.dysign.livetubecountdown E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

As you can see, the process keeps on dying and then restarting, this happens when the phone is both awake and asleep.

Here is how I am starting the AlarmManager (This is inside the widget provider class):

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetAlarmManager.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 1000 , pi);
}
```

And this is the Broadcast Receiver code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main);

    DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetTextView, "TIME = " + format.format(new Date()));

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you, SO!

Comment: The question is why the process keeps dying. Have you done some debugging on that code? Where does it die? How? Why etc ...

Comment: Not exactly, it's quite hard to debug, sometimes the error will occur every 5 seconds, and other times it would be once in 15 minutes.

Comment: Presumably there's more stacktrace?

Comment: Nope, that's it, nothing more. http://i.imgur.com/UBSkID1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see, the process keeps on dying and then restarting, this happens when the phone is both awake and asleep.

In terms of the process dying and restarting, that's not completely surprising. Once your `onReceive()` method returns, Android is welcome to terminate your process whenever it wants to.

In terms of "both awake and asleep", something else is keeping the device awake. By definition, if the device is asleep, the CPU is not executing instructions, and hence there are no logging statements. You can use **`adb shell dumpsys power`** to see who is holding a `WakeLock`.

Comment: So the messages in LogCat are relatively normal, and nothing to worry about?

Comment: @ThomasOwers: "So the messages in LogCat are relatively normal" -- yes. "and nothing to worry about?" -- I wouldn't say that. Updating an app widget every second via `AlarmManager` will result in a fair bit of CPU and RAM churn (as evidenced by the log messages), draining the battery.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only issue, but how do clock widgets do it? Every tutorial/documentation (and the official documentation) says to use a `AlarmManager` as these won;t wake the phone.

Comment: @ThomasOwers: "how do clock widgets do it?" -- a "clock" that ships with the device is probably not an app widget, but part of the home screen activity that feels like an app widget. Third-party clock app widgets hopefully update only once a minute; those that update once per second will suffer the same problems as you or will be using an everlasting service and `ScheduledExecutorService` (a solution which has its own set of problems). The countdown timer app I use skips the app widget and uses a `Notification`, and even that they only update once per minute.